# FTP over SSL, FTPS TLS not working - Rejecting data connection - Only is allowed

Tags: filezilla, tls, winscp, ftps

< 2024-02-08 10:31:19.445 Read 16 bytes

< 2024-02-08 10:31:19.459 200 'TYPE' OK.

< 2024-02-08 10:31:19.459 PASV

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.554 TLS connect: SSL negotiation finished successfully

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.554 TLS connect: SSL negotiation finished successfully

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.554 TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS read server session ticket

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.554 Read 49 bytes

< 2024-02-08 10:31:19.554 227 Entering Passive Mode (102,208,217,16,4,20)

< 2024-02-08 10:31:19.554 MLSD

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.554 Connecting to 102.208.217.16:1044 ...

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.554 Connection pending

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.664 Read 38 bytes

< 2024-02-08 10:31:19.664 150 Opening 'ASCII' data connection.

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.664 Data connection opened

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.664 TLS layer changed state from none to connected

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.774 Read 135 bytes

**< 2024-02-08 10:31:19.774 425-Rejecting data connection from xx.xx.xx.xx1 (only xx.xx.xx.xx2 is allowed).**

< 2024-02-08 10:31:19.774 425 Closing data connection; transfer not started.

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.774 Destroying data socket on error

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.774 Could not retrieve directory listing

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.774 Got reply 4 to the command 2

. 2024-02-08 10:31:19.774 Session upkeep

Now it says Rejecting data connection from **xx.xx.xx.xx1** (only **xx.xx.xx.xx2** is allowed) the IP addresses mentioned are different IP addresses

More information:

Those are NAT Ip addresses and those pair of  IP addresses are same everytime

Comment: Is the client behind any kind of CGNAT? Are the two addresses completely different or are they roughly from the same network?

Comment: The 2 IP addresses are *exactly* the same 2 IPs always. Yes the client is behind 2 NATs and those are the IP addresses Thanks

Comment: What's the network topology like – how do those 2 NATs interact (are they in line or are they two alternate uplinks)? Where is the server, relative to the NATs? At first glance, it seems that your FTP 'control' connection and the 'data' connections get NATed differently from each other, which would likely be a problem with the NATs themselves.

Comment: They are 2 alternate uplinks. And there is no control over traffic splitting. i.e what you said may be correct and control and data connections may be NATed differently. Is there any configuration I can do on the client side?

Comment: Just FYI, there is a discrepancy in your original post. First you mention xx.xx.xx.2 and later you mention xx.xx.xx.xx2

Comment: Thanks Silbee2 corrected the Typo

Comment: On the client side, you should see if the service supports using SFTP instead, which only requires a single connection. You might be able to do some awkward stuff like open another TCP connection in between the FTP, so your next connection uses the same wan IP (assuming the uplinks are getting balanced equally). Other than that, you would need to adjust how your wan connection is configured

Comment: So I take it a FTPS connection is in fact 2 separate connections? If so how do I associate those 2 connections to be the same so that I can configure some rule in the firewall/NAT to consider those 2 as same connection? Thanks